# Get Action and Action Parameters in Controller.OnException

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception

We're using the OnException virtual method in BaseController to log our exception.

But how can we get the controller action and parameters that the exception originated from?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can get all these data from `ExceptionContext` object.

For example using this code you can get controller, action and all other routing parameters:

```
context.RouteData.Values
```

Using this code you can get query string parameters:

```
context.HttpContext.Request.QueryString
```

And finnaly form parameters:

```
context.HttpContext.Request.Form
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the parameters after the ModelBinding parsed them?

Comment: ModelBinding shouldn't change this data. So, that is possible

Comment: What I meant was, I don't want the Request.Querystring\form data, I want it in its Model form - how can I get it?

Comment: @sternr Did you manage to have the data parsed by the modelBinding ?

Answer (score 17):

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
    string action = filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
    string controller = filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as Action Parameters go, you will need to pass them explicitly.

> We don't provide the action arguments on ExceptionContext because it would most often be empty.

Source: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6154

Which is stupid IMO.

**UPDATE:** You could have your error handler class implement [ActionFilterAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2), which implements: 
`public virtual void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)`

where filterContext.**ActionParameters** are what you are looking for.

Comment: error handler class implement ActionFilterAttribute real world sample ?

Comment: @Kiquenet Sorry, seems the code wasn't commited. But I remember that it worked.